# iOS - Photos & message access to MDM installed apps

Tags: iphone, filesystem, mobile-device-management

In iOS, is it possible for apps managed via MDM to get access to photos and text/WhatsApp text messages of user stored on user's iPhone. If yes, what kind of permissions do these actions require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MDM controls how an iOS device is remotely configured and what apps are pushed to be installed. It has nothing to do with what permissions are available to an app.

Reading photos stored on devices requires access to user photos. The mechanism to ask user for photos permission can be programmed by an iOS app developer and would work in the same way irrespective of the way the app is installed (MDM or App Store).

There are **no** permissions/mechanisms available in iOS which can let a third party app read text and WhatsApp messages. Each app is technically sandboxed and need to seek permission from iOS to access user data and device hardware.

Comment: So there is no way to read out such data remotly?

Comment: There is no way for 3rd party apps to read messages from any other messaging app.

Comment: Are there any built in mechanisms within the OS to allow remote parties (e.g. the company of a company phone) to read out such data? I mean without using apps but something else...

Comment: Within the scope of your question - No.

Comment: What kind of scope? Basically I want to know whether it is possible for a company to read out such data from remote? Are there any ways to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Scoped as an end-user of iOS device. Apple may, in certain cases be able to access user data, generally from their own apps, (text messages, photos). But the data never leaves the device (except in case of iCloud backups, which itself is encrypted), is analysed on device. If and when Apple users user data, the same is done in non-user identifiable manner.

Comment: Thank you very much. So if a company provides iphones to its employees, it is not able to read out such data, but can install apps, apply some configurations etc.

Comment: If the company has provided with an MDM managed iPhone, and you have your corporate account setup, be vary that your employer has access to the corporate contacts, email and calendar data (most common scenario).

Comment: Of course it is connected to the exchange server. They will have access to all that content. But not to photos, google drive, whatsapp, etc?

Comment: Yes. Your employer for sure CANNOT read data from any of the 3rd party apps AND user data, specifically Photos, Google Drive, WhatsApp , SMS messages etc.

Comment: I'll edit the answer to add the notes from comments. Accept and Upvote it if your queries are answered.